# [WARN ][plugins] plugin jdbc- river, failed to invoke custom onModule method

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have installed the Elastic search version 1.7.1. It was working fine. I have installed the JDBC driver also. Check my plugins folder below

Directory of `E:\Xampp\htdocs\my-elastic\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\river-jdbc`

```
09-09-2015  19:19            66,891 elasticsearch-river-jdbc-2.3.1.jar
27-07-2015  15:55           959,984 mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar
```

So i have the connector files are in plugins folder. When i start the elasticsearch it shows warning erros as below.

```
[2015-09-10 14:29:48,728][WARN ][plugins                  ] [Rogue] plugin jdbc-
river, failed to invoke custom onModule method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.processModule(PluginsService
.java:200)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsModule.processModule(PluginsModule.j
ava:61)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Modules.processModules(Modules.java:6
4)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(Modules
Builder.java:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java
:210)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:77)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:245)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.xbib.elasticsearch.rest.action.RestJ
DBCRiverInduceAction overrides final method handleRequest.(Lorg/elasticsearch/re
st/RestRequest;Lorg/elasticsearch/rest/RestChannel;)V
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.river.jdbc.JDBCRiverPlugin.onModule(JDB
CRiverPlugin.java:53)
        ... 13 more
```

How can i fix the issue. Please help to fix the issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show how you installed your jdbc river plugin? i.e. `bin/plugin --install ...` or via another way? I'm pretty sure you have an incompatible version of the plugin that doesn't play well with ES 1.7

Comment: Actually i have downloaded the latest version of the jar file in `http://dl.bintray.com/jprante/elasticsearch-plugins/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/2.3.1/%elasticsearch-river-jdbc-2.3.1.jar` path and pasted into the plugins folder. because i don't know how can i update the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JDBC plugin's documentation](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#recent-versions), the version that you should use with ES 1.7 is the version 1.7.0.1.

So try again to install your plugin with the 1.7.0.1 package at
http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/importer/elasticsearch-jdbc/1.7.0.1/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.0.1-dist.zip

And then follow these [installations steps](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#installation)

**UPDATE**

Actually, I didn't get you were trying to install a river plugin. Since [rivers have been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers), the JDBC importer does not provide a river plugin anymore since version 1.5. If you absolutely want to use the river plugin, you need [at most ES 1.5](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/tree/1.5) (i.e. it won't work with ES 1.6+) and the [JDBC plugin v1.5](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/tree/1.5).

If you decide to go down that path, you can install the JDBC river plugin with

```
./bin/plugin --install jdbc --url http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/1.5.0.4/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.5.0.4.zip
```

In the case you decide to stay with ES 1.7, then you can run the JDBC importer as a standalone tool by running the appropriate script in the `bin` folder

Comment: I have downloaded the files, installation steps little bit confusing me. I have two directories in that folder `bin, lib`. what is the next step? I have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar` file in `lib` folder. that is already in my `plugins\river-jdbc` folder. Where i can find the JDBC river jar file?

Comment: I am using the latest version i will choose ES 1.7.  My Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch-River folders are in various path.. How can i import the JDBC to that elasticsearch. Still i am confused with poitns 5,6,7 in Installation steps.